# Failed to create address locator from a CSV file

Tags: csv, address, geocoding

I am using ArcMap Desktop 10.4. I have a CSV file containing the address of properties in 2 fields - civic number and street name. I was trying to create an address locator using the file as the reference data. I selected single house subaddress and made sure all the fields match. But when I clicked OK at the end, it just says failed to create the address locator(Error 000042). I've cleaned the file and tried a few times but it was the same result. what are some possible explanations and how can i work around that? Without creating the address locator, I can't geocode.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [edit] the question to specify what exact GIS software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This locator style uses feature classes with **polygon** or **point** geometry as reference data. Each feature in the reference data corresponds to a single address with subaddress information. You can use a feature class containing building footprints or address points as reference data. You can't use CSV file to create a single house subaddress. Tables or Text files can not be use as a Primary Table but Alias Table, Alternate Table.
If you have xy coordinates of each House address:

1. Import x and y coordinates in the CSV file
2. Create a Point Feature Class with the CSV.
3. Use Point layer to create Address Locator.

Without any XY data:

you can convert addresses to points. The addresses must be in a standard format and you need an Address Locator to reference addresses to a position. You can use World Geocode Service ([World Geocoding](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=305f2e55e67f4389bef269669fc2e284)) [this link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/geocoding-a-table-of-addresses-about.htm) as a locator if you have ArcGIS online licence. Otherwise you should find coordinates of each address manually. as you know, it's not a logical solution for huge amount of addresses.

Comment: what if I don't have any x or y coordinates

Comment: yes, but I was experiencing troubles when trying to create an address locator cuz the one available is not working for this

Comment: Do you have any reference locator? have you try Geocode Addresses tool (in Arctoolbox => Geocoding tools)

Comment: but it still requires an input address locator and there is only MGRS

Comment: Yes it require a reference locator. You need to use World geocoding or another locators .